# PDFlib - saving custom metadata with document page?

Tags: pdflib

Is there any possibility of saving custom metadata with PDF pages using PDFlib API?

How can I save "A" is equal to 1 on page level and later retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might do this with XMP. From the PDFlib 9.2 Tutorial, chapter 11.1:

> XMP can be supplied for pages, fonts, ICC profiles, images, graphics, templates, and imported PDF pages. This can be achieved with the metadata option of various functions, for example:
>   metadata={filename=info.xmp inputencoding=winansi}

Comment: I wonder if the following can be done. Can I set page metadata with $p->begin_page_ext() and later on retrieve it before page is closed?